# Installation shopware with docker on linux and 503 error on

Tags: docker, docker-compose, shopware

I have been installed shopware 6 with docker on my Ubuntu linux. Generally installation has finished without problems. When I'm trying to run this on localhost:8000 I have 503 service unavailable problem like on the screenshoot:
[image]

In console after executing  docker-compose up
I can observed an errors like:

```
app_server_1     | Setting php-fpm user to 0
app_server_1     | [25-Feb-2021 07:11:13] ERROR: [pool www] please specify user and group other than root
app_server_1     | [25-Feb-2021 07:11:13] ERROR: [pool www] please specify user and group other than root
app_server_1     | [25-Feb-2021 07:11:13] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
app_server_1     | [25-Feb-2021 07:11:13] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
app_server_1     | 2021-02-25 07:11:13,941 INFO exited: php-fpmd (exit status 78; not expected)
```

I have added user to docker group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker pirx1988
```

It didn't help me. How should I solve this problem?
I would be greateful for help.

Comment: If you need Shopware on Docker for development purposes, then I can recommend you https://dockware.io/.

Comment: The guess the problem is not with shopware here but with docker permissions.

Comment: Which docker images are you using? How do you start docker / how does the docker-compose file look like? I believe you have to specific the FPM user using a env variable. This should be documented in the docker images you use.